# Passphraseless ssh works but not with Hadoop

Tags: linux, hadoop, ssh, sudo, passphrase

I have installed Hadoop on an Ubuntu machine. I set up passphraseless ssh. I can use the command "ssh localhost" and it gives me information without needing to enter a password. However when I go to Hadoop and type "sudo bin/start-all.sh" it asks me for my password (because I used sudo which is fine), but after I enter that, it will do a couple things and then ask me for the root password which I believe it's not suppose to do. I've searched for a couple days now and I only end up with answers for when "ssh localhost" doesn't work. I haven't found anything for my problem. Any help is very much appreciated.

UPDATE:
  It seems that I need *sudo* passphraseless ssh which is not the same as just passphraseless ssh. However, I am still unable to find out how to make this happen.

Comment: Not an answer, but FYI, I am experiencing this same problem too. Only with connecting to the same machine. My Hadoop cluster has 4 machines all set up the same way, but when starting Hadoop, only that very machine asks me for a password. Good Luck.

Comment: Asking for the root password would indicate it's not an SSH prompt. Something else is doing this, and without seeing the contents of `start-all.sh` it will be difficult for anybody to help.

Comment: mcsilvo - Right now I am just trying to get it to run on a single machine. Once I get this going, learn a bit more about Hadoop, etc, then I will move up to several machines. This seems to be a trick with Ubuntu that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

I just came back to check and realized I didn't post the solution I found. When installing Hadoop and generating keys, avoid using SUDO where ever it is not absolutely necessary. If you use SUDO, it will attempt to use the root keys which are not the same as the ones generated not using SUDO. Hadoop will automatically use the current user's keys and they won't work, so it prompts for a password.

Answer (score 0):

When I stop using

```
**sudo** ./start-dfs.sh
```

And used:

```
./start-dfs.sh
```

I solved the  shh communication problem with the namenode